# "For every line in absorption spectra, the corresponding emission line is present, but the reverse is not true"

Tags: optics, atomic-physics, spectroscopy, absorption, photon-emission

I was studying atomic physics and read the line

> for every line in absorption spectra, the corresponding emission line is present, but the reverse is not true

and I am not able to understand it fully. Can anyone kindly describe it?

Comment: Hint:  In thermal equilibrium, the lower state will be more fully populated.  Emission requires that the upper state be overpopulated, as often happens after rapid cooling.

Answer (score 1):

Say you have a cloud of atomic hydrogen which is reasonably cold, so that only the $n=2$ state has a significant population caused by thermal processes within the cloud, and consider e.g. the $1s \leftrightarrow 3p$ line.

- For absorption, you have a lot of population in the $1s$ state that's ready to absorb radiation at that frequency.
- If you're looking at the emission spectrum of the cloud, there is no $3p$ population that could descend to the $1s$ ground state with the emission of a photon at that frequency, so the line won't be present unless you increase the temperature enough to change that condition.

Generally speaking, *both* absorption and emission spectra are affected by the temperature of the sample, though the effect on the emission spectrum, via the mechanism above, tends to be more evident. It's important to note that there are still similar effects happening in the emission spectrum (consider e.g. the absorption of the $3p \to 4d$ line in the sample above).

It's also important to note that the claim you've quoted is *generally* true, particularly for thermally-populated clouds, but it's not universally true. For a simple counter-example, consider a cloud of atomic hydrogen which has been bombarded with 10.2 eV electrons in such a way that all $1s$ electrons were promoted to the $2p$ level: is there emission of the 10.2 ev $2p\to 1s$ line? Is there absorption in the $1s\to 2p$ process?

Of course, if you're looking at the *fluorescence* spectrum where the cloud has been excited by some external source and it releases that energy by decaying back to the ground state (in some randomized direction), then that line will indeed be present, with basically the same angle-averaged total energy as was originally absorbed (at least, if the density is low enough that the collisional channels for the release of that energy are cut off).

---

> so you are saying, it is not necessary to get the same frequency of absorption line corresponding to that frequency of emission line.

Again, absorption and emission spectra depend on the conditions. For every line in an absorption spectrum, there will be a set of conditions that makes that line show up in an emission spectrum, but there's no guarantee that it will show up as an emission in the same conditions where you're observing it in absorption.

Comment: ok.. it somehow cleared my doubt. thanks for reply.

Comment: If this answers your question, you can click the checkmark button on the left to mark it as accepted.